# Converting a SQL query to Linq using a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

```
select * 
from Enrollment 
where Atnper <= 70
```

I try this in linq but I get an error:

```
var atn = db.Enrollments
            .Where(a => a.cid == cid && 
                        a.Section == sect && 
                        int.Parse(a.Atnper)<= 75)
            .Select(m => m.Atnper);
```

This is the error I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
>
> SystemNotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
>
> StackTrace
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
> at   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
> at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
> linq)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
> parent, BinaryExpression linq)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
> linq)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
> parent, BinaryExpression linq)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
> linq)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression
> lambda, DbExpression input)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
> parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source,
> DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
> parent, MethodCallExpression call)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
> parent, MethodCallExpression linq)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
> linq)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
> parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source,
> DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
> parent, MethodCallExpression call)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
> parent, MethodCallExpression linq)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
> linq)\r\n   at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()\r\n
> at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()\r\n
> at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()\r\n
> at
> System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator>b__0()\r\n
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter
> writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty
> member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
> containerProperty)\r\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
> jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
> jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at
> System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
> type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
> effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
> System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
> type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding
> effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at
> System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
> type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
> TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
> where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__22.MoveNext()"}}

Comment: Have you looked into your error

Comment: AtnPer is a numerical string in the db? Is it always numerical? Turn it into an int column type and fix your entity to use int property and remove the int.Parse

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: Needs details about the class model, mappings, EF version, data types. Also, there are tons of questions on 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method...'. Did you try to find an answer yourself?

Answer (score 2):

From the error it seems you're using EF6 or earlier. I don't think EF has a built in way to invoke a string to number conversion but you could create a user defined function that does it and call that - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd456847(v=vs.100) (but it's a lot of work to get around what is probably a flaw in the data modelling))

--

You could upgrade to EF core and change your int.Parse to `Convert.ToInt32(a.AtnPer)` so that EFC will use `CONVERT(int, AtnPer)` on the db side, but it's a lot of work to get around what is probably a flaw in the data modelling

---

If your column always stores ints in a string, change it to be an int type column and change your C# entity to be int

If you made a mistake in your entity, the db column is an int, and the entity is a string then fix the entity to be int and remove the int parse

Here's a list of functions you can use in an EFC LINQ because it knows how to translate them to something in sql server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions

And the similar advice for older EF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd456828(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

An other way like this:

```
var atn = db.Enrollments
            .Where(a => a.cid == cid && 
                        a.Section == sect && 
                        a.Atnper.Lenght <= 2 && 
                        a.Atnper <= "75")
            .Select(m => m.Atnper);
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that string ordering is different than integer ordering. `"100" < "75"` is true, `100 < 75` is false. That's exactly why they try to parse the string.

Comment: Sure, that's why i added `a.Atnper.Lenght <= 2` but look like that isn't correct. Try this instead: `(a.Atnper.Lenght < 2 || (a.Atnper.Lenght == 2 && a.Atnper <= "75"))`

Comment: Yeah,, but that's an unrealistic limitation.